# Local network batch

Tags: azure-batch, aws-batch

I have been playing around with azure batch for a project at work.
My work has 100-1000s of computers running win10 mostly chewing over Outlook and not much else.

Is there some framework that can leverage 'idle' CPU time in this environment?
Seems a bit of a shame to send tasks to Azure server in US when the 3 or 4 computers around me (in New Zealand) crying for non-fb attention.

I can take downvotes for 'too vague' and 'off topic' - just need a clue where to look.

Answer (score 2):

You will want to investigate machine/CPU time scavenging schedulers such as [HTCondor](https://research.cs.wisc.edu/htcondor/).